# При запуске (экспорте) сцены из Blender в three.js все объекты маленькие

Tags: three.js, blender

Как настроить Blender под three.js?
Запускаю Blender, рисую сцену, а при запуске (экспорте) её в three.js все объекты маленькие. 
Половина даже на экране не видна... Что делать? Как это всё решается?

Comment: если "все" маленькие, имеет смысл привести сцену к этому же масштабу, то есть уже позиции будут не (80,45,23), а (8,4.5,2.3)

Comment: @HashNoobs, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Интересный ответ... Походу оно так и есть... Надо глянуть. чё получится. Но всё же хотелось бы в blendere создовать сцену (и забывать про неё) просто загружать и наблюдать

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, свойство scale, применимое к загруженной модели, Вам поможет.